# error in patch file of doxverilog

Tags: doxygen

I've installed Doxverilog 2.7 and also, downloaded source directories of Doxygen 1.8.1 from this website

```
https://github.com/ewa/doxverilog
```

The setup of doxygen is downloaded from:
    http://sourceforge.net/projects/doxygen/files/

I'm using cygwin along with the installation of bison,  flex, graphviz and qt5 packages on windows. I've also installed unxutills. I followed the general steps provided in the readme file of folder "doxverilog 2.7". When I run this command:

```
patch -F3 -p0 < linux.patch
```

then cygwin (run as administrator) displays different messages. The messages are provided below.

**Messages:**

```
user@user-PC /cygdrive/c/doxverilog-master/doxygen-1.8.1
$ patch -F3 -p0 < linux.patch
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: util.cpp
|===================================================================
|--- util.cpp   (Revision 818)
|+++ util.cpp   (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 52
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: doxygen_css.h
|===================================================================
|--- doxygen_css.h      (Revision 818)
|+++ doxygen_css.h      (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 67
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: navtree_js.h
|===================================================================
|--- navtree_js.h       (Revision 818)
|+++ navtree_js.h       (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 138
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: definition.cpp
|===================================================================
|--- definition.cpp     (Revision 818)
|+++ definition.cpp     (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 167
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: configoptions.cpp
|===================================================================
|--- configoptions.cpp  (Revision 818)
|+++ configoptions.cpp  (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 216
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: ftvhelp.cpp
|===================================================================
|--- ftvhelp.cpp        (Revision 818)
|+++ ftvhelp.cpp        (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
8 out of 8 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 481
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: vhdldocgen.h
|===================================================================
|--- vhdldocgen.h       (Revision 818)
|+++ vhdldocgen.h       (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 496
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: index.cpp 
|===================================================================
|--- index.cpp  (Revision 818) 
|+++ index.cpp  (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 537
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: memberdef.h
|=================================================================== 
|--- memberdef.h        (Revision 818)
|+++ memberdef.h        (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 560
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: definition.h
|===================================================================
|--- definition.h       (Revision 818)
|+++ definition.h       (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 593
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: vhdlparser.y
|===================================================================
|--- vhdlparser.y       (Revision 818)
|+++ vhdlparser.y       (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 615
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: vhdldocgen.cpp
|===================================================================
|--- vhdldocgen.cpp     (Revision 818)
|+++ vhdldocgen.cpp     (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 6945
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: filedef.cpp  
|===================================================================
|--- filedef.cpp        (Revision 818)
|+++ filedef.cpp        (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:  
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 6989
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: image.cpp
|===================================================================
|--- image.cpp  (Revision 818)
|+++ image.cpp  (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 7049
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: doxygen.cpp
|===================================================================
|--- doxygen.cpp        (Revision 818)
|+++ doxygen.cpp        (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
7 out of 7 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 7124
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: config.l
|===================================================================
|--- config.l   (Revision 818)
|+++ config.l   (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
4 out of 4 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 7179
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: util.h
|===================================================================
|--- util.h     (Revision 818)
|+++ util.h     (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 7191
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: image.h
|===================================================================
|--- image.h    (Revision 818)
|+++ image.h    (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 7204
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: classdef.cpp
|===================================================================
|--- classdef.cpp       (Revision 818)
|+++ classdef.cpp       (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
10 out of 10 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 7329
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: htmlgen.cpp
|===================================================================
|--- htmlgen.cpp        (Revision 818)
|+++ htmlgen.cpp        (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 7364
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: types.h
|===================================================================
|--- types.h    (Revision 818)
|+++ types.h    (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 7378
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: memberdef.cpp
|===================================================================
|--- memberdef.cpp      (Revision 818)
|+++ memberdef.cpp      (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
5 out of 5 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 7432
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: translator_en.h
|===================================================================
|--- translator_en.h    (Revision 818)
|+++ translator_en.h    (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 7447
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: vhdlscanner.l
|===================================================================
|--- vhdlscanner.l      (Revision 818)
|+++ vhdlscanner.l      (Arbeitskopie)
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
5 out of 5 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 7585
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: libdoxygen.pro.in
|===================================================================
|--- libdoxygen.pro.in  2011-08-03 12:28:25.000000000 +0100
|+++ libdoxygen.pro.in  2011-11-12 17:06:04.000000000 +0000
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
4 out of 4 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 7625
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: libdoxygen.pro.in 
|===================================================================
|--- libdoxygen.t       2011-08-03 12:37:56.000000000 +0200
|+++ libdoxygen.t       2011-11-12 17:06:04.000000000 +0100
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

When I run the following command after these messages.

```
sh configure
```

The following messages are displayed:

**Messages:**

```
Autodetected platform win32-g++...
Checking for GNU make tool... using /cygdrive/c/UnxUtils/usr/local/wbin/make
Checking for GNU install tool... using /usr/bin/install
Checking for dot (part of GraphViz)... using /usr/bin/dot
Checking for perl... using /usr/bin/perl
Checking for flex... using /usr/bin/flex
Checking for bison... using /usr/bin/bison
Creating VERSION file.
Created doxygen.spec file, for rpm generation.
Created Makefile from Makefile.in...
Created qtools/Makefile from qtools/Makefile.in...
Created src/Makefile from src/Makefile.in...
Created examples/Makefile from examples/Makefile.in...
Created doc/Makefile from doc/Makefile.in...
Created addon/doxywizard/Makefile from addon/doxywizard/Makefile.in...
Created addon/doxmlparser/src/Makefile from
addon/doxmlparser/src/Makefile.in...
Created addon/doxmlparser/test/Makefile from
addon/doxmlparser/test/Makefile.in...
Created addon/doxmlparser/examples/metrics/Makefile from
addon/doxmlparser/examples/metrics/Makefile.in...
Created libmd5/Makefile from libmd5/Makefile.in...
Created addon/doxyapp/Makefile from addon/doxyapp/Makefile.in...
Created qtools/qtools.pro from qtools/qtools.pro.in...
Created src/libdoxygen.pro from src/libdoxygen.pro.in...
Created src/libdoxycfg.pro from src/libdoxycfg.pro.in...
Created src/doxygen.pro from src/doxygen.pro.in...
Created addon/doxywizard/doxywizard.pro from
addon/doxywizard/doxywizard.pro.in...
Created addon/doxmlparser/src/doxmlparser.pro from
addon/doxmlparser/src/doxmlparser.pro.in...
Created addon/doxmlparser/test/xmlparse.pro from
addon/doxmlparser/test/xmlparse.pro.in...
Created addon/doxmlparser/examples/metrics/metrics.pro from
addon/doxmlparser/examples/metrics/metrics.pro.in...
Created libmd5/libmd5.pro from libmd5/libmd5.pro.in...
Created addon/doxyapp/doxyapp.pro from addon/doxyapp/doxyapp.pro.in...
Generating src/lang_cfg.h...
```

Now, when I run the following command

```
make all
```

the the following messages are dislayed:

**Messages:**

```
echo "char versionString[]=\"1.8.1\";" > src/version.cpp
/cygdrive/c/UnxUtils/usr/local/wbin/make -C qtools
process_begin: CreateProcess((null),
/cygdrive/c/UnxUtils/usr/local/wbin/make -C qtools, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
C:\UnxUtils\usr\local\wbin\make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please help me in this problem.

Thank-you.

Comment: For which version of doxygen is Doxverilog 2.6 intended? From the messages in the log file it looks to me that it is not intended for doxygen 1.8.10 as this version uses cmake and does not contain files like src/libdoxygen.pro.in anymore.

Comment: Doxverilog  2.6 was easily downloaded without crashing but the new releases lie 2.7 and 2.8 keeps on crashing at every time while downloading. Also, there is only doygen 1.8.10 on doxgen's website. Can you help me out of it?

Comment: See http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/download.html here is a link to ftp://ftp.stack.nl/pub/users/dimitri/  with a collection of older versions.

Comment: Another link is http://sourceforge.net/projects/doxygen/files/

Comment: please find edits in the question

Comment: Looks like entire question has been changed. Version 1.8.1 is quite old and I don't think it can be used with qt5. Furthermore the patch process looks like it didn't succeed. Best Guess is to get help from the doxyverilog developers. I don't know about the relation between the verilog language and vhdl, but doxygen "supports" vhdl.

Comment: yeah! it suorts vhdl and vhd files but i need to have the documentation of verilog .v files

Comment: how do I connect with doxverilog developers?

Comment: Did you try to use *.v with FILE_PATTERNS and setting in EXTENSION_MAPPING the mapping between the v files and vhdl. Regarding contacting the doxyverilog developers, you could maybe try to contact the owner of the github repository.

Comment: It adds .v files but their documentation isn't done. Do I need to create a new issue on GitHub?

Comment: Issue should be created in bugzilla, including example (without using doxyvberilog) showing the problem and the used Doxyfile.

Answer (score 0):

try
https://bitbucket.org/maddoxx/doxverilog
checkout branch 1810

read BUILD.txt!!!
run cmake -h

Comment: which doxverilog version is compatible with doxygen 1.8.10 ? becasue I was able to compile this doxygen version safely but the recent doxverilog seems to incompatible with it..